# Is this question unanswered because no one knows, or because Stack Overflow is the wrong place?

Tags: support

[General considerations for NUI/touch interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463002/general-considerations-for-nui-touch-interface)

Comment: That question sounds more like a subject for a big research or for a  thesis, however, SO can take good care of specific questions.And with SO I mean us.Also, that is a good subject.

Comment: The question is just one day old; not all the questions receive an answer twenty-four hours after they are asked.

Comment: 'Not constructive'

Answer (score 19):

It is not answered because your question is, well, *general* (just like you said), and requires the readers to spend some time in deep thought before answering.

A quote from the faq seems especially relevant here:

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

It's not hard to imagine your scenario (as presented) consuming a room full of bright minds for a whole day.

Your question might have gotten more attention if it had been more focused on one specific aspect.  It took me awhile to realize that one of your goals might be to size the screen (and its controls) proportionally to the device it is running on.

Not trying to be glib, but some pictures (and some freehand circles) demonstrating the concepts you're trying to convey would have helped!

Answer (score 6):

...or because it is such a specific and niche question that it takes more then the average time to attract not only interested but certainly experienced visitors. The question just has 8 views for now and has no upvotes. That is saying that those 8 people were interested, but maybe have no experience to answer or vote for the question. I myself do not dare to upvote because I cannot fully evaluate its usefullness.

Just wait a little longer.

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of asking a number of stupid questions:

What is NUI? What about the z axis? I don't have a Kinect, but I thought that device worked in 3D, not 2D. Are you planning to intersect its view with a pane of glass or something? Why XML? What is the point of selecting a data format right now?

I'd also reduce the scope of each problem. Before targeting all synths for instance, I'd suggest you at least get it working with one. And before thinking about all the virtual objects you'd like to support, I'd suggest you get it working with at least one object. Write some unit-tests. Focus on those.

I'd also suggest you try to break your question down into much smaller bite-sized questions (each posted separately on Stackoverflow). For instance, I can easily see your problem getting broken down in at least 10 different questions (some of which you'll probably be able to easily solve yourself after you've broken them down).

And please include some embedded sketches or pictures in your questions, I may be unable to answer any of your technical questions, but at least I can appreciate questions explained with illustrations and I can at least up-vote them.

Comment: NUI: New user Interfaces - a generic term for multitouch interfaces using some combination of touchpads, fiducial tracking, and machine vision. Yes, the kinect has a depth map, but it's currently not widely implemented. Re images, will probably work on those today. Re 1 synth, I'm specifically looking for a generic solution. It is trivial to create individual setups on a synth-by-synth basis. What is needed is a generic solution usable by somebody who doesn't understand the software as well as I. Thus the requirement to create the interface programatically or algorithmically.

Comment: I think the best way for you and I, as well as most useful to stack overflow, to exchange information is via chat. If you're okay with that, go ahead and open a chatroom and I'll join assuming my reputation is high enough. If not, we'll go ahead and use comments.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've broken the problem down into more manageable chunks you might find that Programmers or User Experience are better sites for some of your questions.

**Programmers** - From the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in conceptual questions on software development.
>
> This can include topics such as:
>
> - Algorithm and data structure concepts
> - Design patterns
> - Architecture

So you can see that some of your questions would fit here, but you'd still have to break things down into specific issues.

**User Experience** - There's not much in the [FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) but questions on how usable something might be or which methodologies to use to evaluate your UI are on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed would have been better if broken down but I've replied with an answer to the original question